# Given that $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of S with eigenvalue $\lambda$ , prove that T(v) is also an eigenvector of S with eigenvalue $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have $S,T \in L(V,V)$ and can assume TS = ST
How can we go from eigenvector v to eigenvector T(v)?
I tried showing if $\lambda = 0$ then $v \in Ker(S)$ and if $\lambda \neq 0$ then $v \in Range(S)$ (not even sure if my argument for it being in the range is correct), but I'm stuck here. Any help?

Comment: All you have to do is prove that $STv=\lambda Tv$. You know $ST=TS$ and $Sv=\lambda v$.

Comment: In general, the claim as stated is wrong. An eigenvector of $S$ wit iegenvalue $\lambda$ is defined to be a *non-zero* vector $v$ with $S(v)=\lambda v$. If $$ is the zero map, we have $ST=TS$ but for any eigenvector $v$ of $S$, $T(v)=0$ is not an eigenvector

Answer (score 2):

Remark: We need to further impose the condition that $T(v)$ is non-zero as pointed out by Hagen.

let $v$ be an eigenvector of $S$, you want to verify $T(v)$ is an eigenvector as well.

so compute

$$S(T(v))=T(S(v))=T(\lambda v)$$

Do you see why $T(v)$ is an eigenvector now?

Comment: This shows that $T(v)$ is  in th e$\lambda$-eigenspace, but it need not be an eigenvector

Comment: Yes. Take out the scalar, and we have $STv = \lambda Tv$.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for pointing out the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

$v\in \mathrm{Null}(S-\lambda I)$
$$T(S-\lambda I)v=(S-\lambda I)Tv$$
as $TS=ST$.